# How to create animated Counter in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

This counter's number(sum of something or count of something) will be increased dynamically if data/value is increased in database or table. User can see this counter's number increment.

Here's an example: I want a widget showing: "# of rooms checked in": .  The number could go up and down: 55->56->58->52. It would be nice to show some animation like flipping a card, when the numbers changed

Comment: you can do this. Please edit your question with more information of what you would like to increment. Are you trying to show the sum of something, or a refresh date? Every time your dataset refreshes, you will get new data. Are you doing an import model?